# Grades Calculator (if else statements)

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I make a simple calculator that returns student ratings based on the given criteria. But program display only 4 of them (should be 15!). How should i solve it?

```
students_score = [57, 89, 23, 26, 68, 95, 100, 58, 51, 90, 18, 42, 49, 51, 67]
students_grades = {}

print("Students score in percents: " + '\n', students_score, '\n')


def grade_counter():
    for i in students_score:
        if i in range(51, 101):
            good_grade = 'You passed the exam :D'
            if i in range(90, 101):
                students_grades.update({'5': f'{i} % , {good_grade}'})
            elif i in range(70, 90):
                students_grades.update({'4': f'{i} %, {good_grade}'})
            elif i in range(51, 70):
                students_grades.update({'3': f'{i} %, {good_grade}'})
        else:
            bad_grade = 'You fail the exam :('
            if i in range(0, 51):
                students_grades.update({'2': f'{i} %, {bad_grade}'})

    print(students_grades)


grade_counter()

#OUTPUT:
Students score in percents: 
 [57, 89, 23, 26, 68, 95, 100, 58, 51, 90, 18, 42, 49, 51, 67] 

{'3': '67 %, You passed the exam :D', '4': '89 %, You passed the exam :D', '2': '49 %, You fail the exam :(', '5': '90 % , You passed the exam :D'}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that you are updating the `students_grades` dictionary inside the loop, which means it overwrites the values for the same grade each time. To solve this issue, you should use the student's index as the key in the `students_grades` dictionary. Also, you don't need to check if the score is in a specific range multiple times. You can simplify the code.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
students_score = [57, 89, 23, 26, 68, 95, 100, 58, 51, 90, 18, 42, 49, 51, 67]
students_grades = {}

print("Students score in percents: " + '\n', students_score, '\n')


def grade_counter():
    for index, score in enumerate(students_score):
        if 90 <= score <= 100:
            students_grades[index] = f'{score}%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 5'
        elif 70 <= score < 90:
            students_grades[index] = f'{score}%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 4'
        elif 51 <= score < 70:
            students_grades[index] = f'{score}%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3'
        elif 0 <= score <= 50:
            students_grades[index] = f'{score}%, You fail the exam :('

    print(students_grades)


grade_counter()
```

Output:

```
Students score in percents: 
 [57, 89, 23, 26, 68, 95, 100, 58, 51, 90, 18, 42, 49, 51, 67] 

{0: '57%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3', 1: '89%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 4', 2: '23%, You fail the exam :(', 3: '26%, You fail the exam :(', 4: '68%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3', 5: '95%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 5', 6: '100%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 5', 7: '58%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3', 8: '51%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3', 9: '90%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 5', 10: '18%, You fail the exam :(', 11: '42%, You fail the exam :(', 12: '49%, You fail the exam :(', 13: '51%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3', 14: '67%, You passed the exam :D, Grade: 3'}
```